# SQL SELECT COUNT GROUP BY - error

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I am having a problem with my sql statement, I have two tables (ogrenci and taksit). I am trying to count the number of taksits where they are zero and group them by KategoriID.KategoriID is both in ogrenci and taksit tables while odendi is only in taksit table.  I could not find where the error is. 
my sql is as follows

```
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT KategoriID, ad, odendi, COUNT(odendi) FROM ogrenci INNER JOIN taksit ON ogrenci.KategoriID = taksit.KategoriID and WHERE odendi=0 GROUP BY KategoriID");
    while($listele = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
    {

        $KategoriID = $listele['KategoriID'];
        $ad = $listele["ad"];
        $odendi = $listele["odendi"];
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple rule:  never use commas in the `from` clause.  Always use explicit `join`s:

```
SELECT t.KategoriID, ad, odendi, COUNT(odendi)
FROM taksit t INNER JOIN
     ogrenci o
     ON o.KategoriID = t.KategoriID 
WHERE odendi = 0
GROUP BY t.KategoriID;
```

You should also use table aliases and qualify all column names.

Comment: I got this error mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: That usually means there is a syntax error in the query.  One problem is that `KategoriID` is ambiguous, but I just fixed that.  You should look at the error produced when you run the query.

Answer (score 1):

The JOIN was incorrect, plus the WHERE clause was incorrect. Try this:

```
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT KategoriID, ad, odendi, COUNT(odendi) FROM ogrenci INNER JOIN taksit ON ogrenci.KategoriID = taksit.KategoriID WHERE odendi=0 GROUP BY KategoriID");
```

Here is the formatted SQL for easier reading:

```
  SELECT t.KategoriID, 
         ad, 
         t.odendi, 
         COUNT(t.odendi) 
  FROM ogrenci o
  INNER JOIN taksit t ON o.KategoriID = t.KategoriID 
  WHERE t.odendi = 0 
  GROUP BY t.KategoriID
```

Comment: I got this error mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: $sql= mysql_query("SELECT KategoriID, ad, odendi, COUNT(odendi) FROM ogrenci INNER JOIN taksit ON ogrenci.KategoriID = taksit.KategoriID and WHERE odendi=0 GROUP BY KategoriID");
  while($listele = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
  {

   $KategoriID = $listele['KategoriID'];
   $ad = $listele["ad"];
   $odendi = $listele["odendi"];

Comment: check what is in $sql.

Comment: if (!$sql) die("query failed"); // test for valid $sql

Comment: if I use "or die(mysql_error()" I get syntax error, unexpected '{' in while

Comment: That means there is a problem with the query. They syntax is correct, can you update the question with the data types of the columns and some sample data?

Comment: I get Undefined variable: for KategoriID, ad, odendi

Comment: I have updated the sql to include aliases, but I am not sure what table ad is in.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the syntax here and there should not be an `and` after the second table's name. The syntax should be:

```
SELECT ....
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON ....
```

So the correct query will be:

```
SELECT KategoriID, ad, odendi, COUNT(odendi) 
FROM ogrenci INNER JOIN 
      taksit ON ogrenci.KategoriID = taksit.KategoriID 
WHERE odendi=0 
GROUP BY KategoriID
```

Comment: I got this error mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why if you're grouping you don't add all the columns in the group list... try this:

```
SELECT ogrenci.KategoriID, ad, odendi, COUNT(odendi) 
FROM ogrenci INNER JOIN 
  taksit ON ogrenci.KategoriID = taksit.KategoriID 
WHERE odendi=0 
GROUP BY KategoriID, ad, odendi
```